# Programmatically translate C# to IL

Tags: c#

I have my portfolio which uses the CSharpCodeProvider namespace to programmatically compile user entered code. Is there a class in Reflection or one of the "CSharp" namespaces which will allow me to translate C# to MSIL?

How does Reflector or LINQPad do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflector translates IL to C#.

What you want is the opposite.

It's called `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` .

You programmatically configure it, but then it runs the csc.exe compiler to generate whatever you like.  If you set the target to "netmodule" I guess it would generate bare IL.

Comment: Thanks! I was just on MSDN's C# class reference library looking for the right class, but I was looking in the Assembly classes. When I mentioned "CSharp", I was talking about Microsoft.CSharp.xxx. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [System.Reflection.Emit namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx).